# Assign a spring proxy using Java Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have this piece of code

```
<bean id="proxy"
        class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean"
        p:target-ref="john" p:interceptorNames-ref="advisorNames">
    </bean>

    <bean id="documentarist"
        class="com.aop.declarative.Documentarist"
        p:guitarist-ref="proxy" />
```

I want to do similar configuration using Java Config.

```
@Bean
    public ProxyFactoryBean factoryBean() {
        ProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setTarget(guitarist());
        factoryBean.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        factoryBean.addAdvisor(pointcutAdvisor());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Documentarist documentarist() {
        Documentarist documentarist = new Documentarist();
        documentarist.setGuitarist(guitarist());
        return documentarist;
    }
```

In this line of code `documentarist.setGuitarist(guitarist());` instead of guitarist(), I want to use `factoryBean()` so the proxied guitarist is injected as we do in xml. How do we do that using Java configuration?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting this is the solution I found.

```
documentarist.setGuitarist((Guitarist) factoryBean().getObject());
```

Because the `ProxyFactoryBean` implements `FactoryBean`, its `getObject()` returns the Object being proxied. Because it returns Object, it was casted to the correct type.